# Need help on a short proof

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Prove that on $(0,1)$ that $$-\ln(x)/(1-x) < 1/\sqrt{x}$$.

I tried looking at the derivative but didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

For $x \in (0,1)$, you have $1 - x \gt 0$, so

$$-\frac{\ln(x)}{1-x} \lt \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \iff -\ln(x) \lt \frac{1 - x}{\sqrt{x}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} - \sqrt{x} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

I believe using this to create a function to check its values and derivative should be considerably easier than using the original inequality.

**Update:** Since the OP has stated below they already previously determined this inequality, here is how to go further. You can create a function

$$f(x) = \ln(x) + \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} - \sqrt{x} \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Note $f(1) = 0$. Also, you have

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
f'(x) & = \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{2x^{3/2}} - \frac{1}{2x^{1/2}} \\
& = \frac{1}{2x^{3/2}}(2x^{1/2} - 1 - x) \\
& = -\frac{1}{2x^{3/2}}(1 - \sqrt{x})^2
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Thus, the derivative is negative for $x \in (0,1)$, so the value of $f(x)$ is strictly decreasing to $f(1) = 0$. This shows that $f(x) \gt 0$ for $x \in (0,1)$, which confirms that \eqref{eq1A} holds.

Comment: what sort of function should I create though?

Comment: @Zexion12 You could move the $\ln(x)$ to the right, for example, and then show that $f(x) = \ln(x) + \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} - \sqrt{x}$ is always positive.

Comment: yes, I had this inequality but this is where I don't know where to go.

Comment: Does this not assume that the function is positive before it decreases to 1?

Comment: @Zexion12 It would have been useful if you had stated in your question text that you had already progressed to the inequality I stated. As such, I have deleted my earlier comment & put the rest of the details into the answer itself. As for the assumption the function is positive before it decreases to $1$, actually, I show that $f(1) = 0$, but $f'(x) \lt 0$ for $x \in (0,1)$, so it must be *decreasing* to $0$. As such, you have that $f(x)$ *must* be positive for $x \lt 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that, for $x\in (0,1)$,

$$\frac1{\sqrt{x}}+\frac{ \ln x}{1-x}=\frac1{1-x}\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt x}-\sqrt x + \ln x\right)=\frac1{1-x}\int_x^1 \left( \frac1{2t^{3/2}} + \frac1{2t^{1/2}} - \frac1t\right)dt$$
$$=\frac1{1-x}\int_x^1  \frac{(1-t^{1/2})^2}{2t^{3/2}}>0$$

Thus,

$$-\frac{ \ln x}{1-x}< \frac1{\sqrt{x}}$$